# Media test failure error in Minicom

Tags: grub2, boot-repair, pxe, serial-port, minicom

I have been working on setting up a bare metal switch through minicom from a remote server.
Serial port info:

```
sudo setserial -g /dev/ttyS0
/dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
```

I was playing around with the grub2 configurations. 
And I remember updating grub? (update-grub).

Now I can't see any option to access boot loader in the system. 
No command seems to work except, `exit` on mininet console.
And that gives error:

```
PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable
PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel Boot Agent.
```

[Fig:- Error displayed on mininet console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFS1p.png)

**Update:**
The partitions of the firmware(ONIE) of the switch seems to be messed up somehow. I can access the BIOS mode. I guess I will have to reinstall the ONIE from web sources. 
Please let me know if my guess is right. Or is there any chance that my Minicom configuration itself has some problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by reinstalling the ONIE firmware of my switch.

I think the problem was that I had somehow installed an incompatible NOS on my switch which in turn messed up with the partitions of the grub2 boot loader.

So I created the ONIE image and attached the binary through usb. I then got my grub screen back through minicom.